Can $p$-adic functional analysis be applied to algebraic geometry?
I learned that $L^2$ estimate based on funtional analysis could be used to prove some vanishing theorems of cohomology of coherent analytic sheaves over complex manifolds or complex projective varieties.
Then I wonder whether there are similar ideas about using $p$-adic funtional analysis to prove some vanishing theorems of cohomology of "coherent analytic sheaves" over "$p$-adic projective varieties".
